# RunTime error in code c++

Tags: c++, runtime-error

I am running this code::

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int findNumbers(int number, int power);
int findPow(int base, int power);
int fact(int n);

int main() {
    int n;
    cin >> n;
    cout << findNumbers(n, 1);
}

int findNumbers(int number, int power) {
    int powerOf10 = findPow(10, power);
    int numberTemp = number / (powerOf10/10);
    int currentDigit = numberTemp % powerOf10; //errorLine

    if (number/(powerOf10/10) == 0)
        return 0;

    int ans = findNumbers(number, power + 1);
    int *digits = new int[10]();
    for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        digits[i] = 0;
    for(int i = power - 1; i > 0; i--) {
        int power10temp = findPow(10, i);
        int digitTemp = number % power10temp;
        digits[digitTemp]++;
    }
    digits[currentDigit]++;
    int numerator = fact(power - 1);
    for(int i = currentDigit + 1; i < 10; i++) {
        int denominator = 1;
        if(digits[i] != 0) {
            digits[i]--;
            for(int j = 0; j < 10; j++) {
                denominator = denominator * fact(digits[i]);
            }
            ans = ans + (numerator/denominator);
            digits[i]++;
        }
    }
    delete digits;
    cout << ans << endl;
    return ans;
}

int fact(int n) {
    if (n <= 1)
        return 1;
    return n*fact(n-1);
}

int findPow(int base, int power) {
    int ans = 1;
    for(int i = 0; i < power; i++) {
        ans = ans * base;
    }
    return ans;
}
```

I have been trying to run this code in my CodeBlocks and Netbeans IDE. But, in both cases the program hangs in between, probably because of some runtime error. But, when I try to run it on the ideone compiler, it runs without any errors.

**What I tried doing?**

I was trying to solve a question, where we have to find the number of "numbers", formed with the same digits as that of the original number. So, I am trying to use permutations and combinations formulas to get the number of numbers greater.

**See the code, there is a line where I have commented "errorLine"**.
If I change that line of the code to this::

```
    int currentDigit = numberTemp % 10;
```

Then my program terminates!
So, probably there is something wrong with this line. But I don't know what could be wrong with a modulus statement.

And why is it that on my system, on both the IDEs codeblocks and NetBeans, have become faulty??

P.S. I know the code is logically is incorrect.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: One problem: `delete digits;` should be `delete [] digits;`

Comment: Do you know how to step through your code in a debugger?

Comment: @PaulR It worked. Thank you so much. Can you post it as an answer so I can accept?? Probably the modulus line was just a random click.

Comment: @DrewDormann yes I do, but it also kindof hanged, after the second or third time, it passed my breakpoint.

Comment: @coderzz027: glad it helped - comment now converted to answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use `new []` to allocate memory then you need to use `delete []` to free it. So:

```
delete digits;
```

should be:

```
delete [] digits;
```

Answer (score 2):

Your integer overflows when computing `powerOf10` (which already causes UB) and becomes negative.

You cannot take the remainder of a division by a negative number.

Obviously `10` cannot ever overflow, so your test does not exhibit the same behavior.

Comment: Didn't understand, how the integer overflows?? my input was `123` when I tried running it.

Comment: Have a look at [this](https://ideone.com/Dvm2Xx). Maybe your example is flawed, but it is certainly exhibiting this behavior. (Note that the error already explained by Paul R has been fixed in that example, but everything else is just as you posted it-)